How can I define a custom TikZ path operation?
How feasible is it to define my own path operations, similar to --, to, rectangle, or parabola in TikZ? Specifically, I am looking to create custom commands that could be used in a drawing command like the following:
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1) myshape (2,3) parabola (4,2);

I haven't found any documentation or Stack Exchange discussions addressing this topic.

Maybe have a look at section "18.2 The Pic Syntax" of the tikz user guide

Have a look at tikz-ext for an example of a package which adds path operations, maybe? But I'm not sure whether you could apply it to parabolas.

It should be posible to create a custom to[myshape], after all, circuitikz does it all the time.

tikz-ext looks promising. parabola is already defined by TikZ. I used it just as an example of something that is already working. I'm familiar with syntax like to[myshape], but that's not what I'm looking for.

@ttsc I've missed your comment here before answering. Is there a reason you don't like to[myshape]? Can you give a specification of a myshape operation?


How feasible is it to define my own path operations, similar to --, to, rectangle, or parabola in TikZ?

Depends on

your input syntax
If you need \path (1,1) myshape (3,3); you will need to hook
into the TikZ parser which basically eats it way through a path
until it finds a ;.
Consider the \tikz@handle macro.
It looks at the next character and switches to an appropriate macro.
If the next character it sees is a (
it will start the subparser for an absolute coordinate,
if it is a + it will start the subparser for a relative coordinate.
A -, though, isn't enough.
It still needs to look at the second next character to
decide between -- and -| which it does in the \tikz@lineto macro –
and here it also differentiate between an other | and an active |.
For the characters you see in \tikz@handle you can basically hook into
that letter by redefining the macro that gets called after finding that letter.
The character m is not part of this which means adjusting this is a bit more
complicated and less forgiving. Unfortunately, there is no proper hook built-in
to adjust this parser.



It is much easier, if you'd allow the synax \path (1,1) \myshape (3,3);.
This sidesteps the whole TikZ parser disaster. But you still then need to write
a small parser that deals with the following coordinate and also with nodes,
pics and coordinates if you allow them to implcitly be placed along your
path operation.

if you allow objects to be placed along the path
Speaking of nodes, pics and coordinates (“objects”):
The main path operations allow objects to be placed along it.
For this, each path operation installs a timer and at least two macros that
are needed for the timer. The timer's job is to convert the value of
the \tikz@time macro (which will hold the value given to the pos key)
to a point, preferably along the path specified by your path operation.


These are the main points really.
After parsing everything between your path operation and the coordinate behind it,
you have everything you need to calculate the actual path to be drawn between them.
(Well, you still need to take care of non-coordinate nodes since usually a path segment should start at the border of a node. In the source, the keywords for this are flush and moveto@waiting.)
Usually, your path is constructed by a sequence of \pgfpath… macros which means, you also need to learn a bit of PGF.
Though, I'd argue you could also construct a TikZ path segment that does the same and simply give this back to the TikZ parser.

However, at that point, you've really reinvented the to path operation. (The edge path operation is also a to but creates a separate path.)
The to path operation already parses everything you need and packages it in three macros:

\tikztostart, i.e. the start coordinate,
\tikztotarget, i.e. the end coordinate, and
\tikztonodes, i.e. all the objects that have been collected.

There are some edge-cases concerning \tiktzostart and \tikztotarget but usually that's it.
This would mean, your input syntax is \path (1,1) to[my shape] (3,3); where my shape is a style that sets at least to path.
There are many, many examples on this site that use a custom to path to achieve semetimes the most special kind of paths and sometimes just the simplest that many miss when using TikZ.
The to paths don't solve everything.
Depending on your custom path segment, you still need to sort out whether \tikztostart/\tikztotarget contain an anchor-less node name and the timer used will depend on where you place \tikztonodes.

Since you didn't specify how your myshape should look like, I've took the liberty to implemente an anti line to to path as an example that instead of drawing a line between two nodes, it draws two lines, each half the length of the normal connecting line, but away from the nodes.
Again, this doesn't use the length between the centers of the nodes but the length between the borders of the nodes. To find this half-length, an invisible edge is used to place a coordinate at the halfway point which is then later rotated around the start and end coordinate. This will also work if only one or even both of them are simple coordinates (and not nodes with a shape).
For the timer, we will save four additional coordinates: for each half-line, the start and the end point will be saved.
The time is simply installed right before \tikztonodes.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{set timer/.code=\let\tikz@timer#1}
\newcommand*\tikzGetTime[1]{\let#1\tikz@time}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\tikzTimerAntiLine{%
  \tikzGetTime\tikzTime
  % the /tikz/pos key makes sure that \tikz@time contains a simple number
  % and is thus usable by \ifdim
  \ifdim\tikzTime pt<.5pt
    \pgftransformlineattime{2*\tikzTime}{\pgfpointanchor{@start}{center}}
                                        {\pgfpointanchor{@smid}{center}}%
  \else
    \pgftransformlineattime{2*(1-\tikzTime)}{\pgfpointanchor{@end}{center}}
                                            {\pgfpointanchor{@emid}{center}}%
  \fi
}
\tikzset{
  anti line to/.style={
    to path={
      % an edge uses also to path and the macros \tikztostart/\tikztotarget
      % which is why we need to save them or need to do
      % \expanded{(\tikztostart) edge[…] (\tikztotarget)}
      % to avoid infinite recursion
      \pgfextra{\let\tts\tikztostart\let\ttt\tikztotarget}
      % first, let's find the middle point between the borders of start and end
      (\tts) edge[line to, path only] coordinate[midway] (@mid) (\ttt)
      (\tikztostart)
        -- coordinate[at start] (@start)
      ([rotate around=180:(\tikztostart )]@mid) coordinate (@smid)
      ([rotate around=180:(\tikztotarget)]@mid) coordinate (@emid)
        -- coordinate[at   end] (@end)
      (\tikztotarget)
      [set timer=\tikzTimerAntiLine]\tikztonodes
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \ang in {0, 10, ..., 179}{%
  \path[nodes={draw, circle}]
    node (Foo) at (\ang:-.5-sqrt \ang/4) {Foo}
    node (FBr) at (\ang:1.5+sqrt \ang/3) {Foo Bar};
  
  \draw (Foo) to[anti line to]
              node foreach[count=\i from 0, evaluate={\c=\pos/.01;}]
                \pos in {.1, .25, .4, .49, .5, .6, .75, .9} [
                  pos=\pos, circle=shape, draw, fill=red!\c!blue, inner sep=+2pt,
                  label={[%
                    node font=\tiny,
                    label position={\ang+ifthenelse(\pos<.5,90,-90)}]\pos}
                ] {}
        (FBr);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output

